# Can I rely on a function-scoped static variable for a method called during program shutdown?

Tags: c++, static, destructor

Quick context: I'm seeing errors on program shutdown, that stem from dependencies between global members (*::sigh::*, I know, I know). One global variable's destructor might refer to another global -- and if that one's already been destructed, things get bad.

But here's a particular case where I just don't know whether behavior is well-defined: **a static variable inside a function.** Can I rely on the function behaving consistently even during program shutdown? Or is it possible that the static member will be destroyed, and the function will run anyway, without creating a new one?

Here's a toy example demonstrating what I'm interested in:

```cpp
class Logger
{
public:
    enum class Severity { DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR };
    void Log(Severity sev, const std::string& msg)
    {
        LogImpl(FormatMessage(sev, msg));
    }

    Logger() { Log(Severity::INFO, "Logger active"); }
    ~Logger() { Log(Severity::INFO, "Logger inactive"); }

protected:
    static std::string FormatMessage(Severity sev, const std::string& msg)
    {
        static const std::map<Severity, std::string> enum2str {
            {Severity::DEBUG, "DEBUG"},
            {Severity::INFO, "INFO"},
            {Severity::WARNING, "WARNING"},
            {Severity::ERROR, "ERROR"}
        };

        // Throws or crashes if enum2str is invalid, or uninitialized:
        return "[" + enum2str[sev] + "] " + msg;
    }
    void LogImpl(const std::string& msg)
    {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Let's imagine I have a global instance of `Logger`. The `enum2str` map in `Logger::FormatMessage` is a static variable, so at some point during program shutdown, it will be destroyed.

By standard, **can this cause my program to crash on shutdown?** Is `enum2str` inherently unreliable during shutdown? Or is there some handling of this -- for example, if `enum2str` is invalid at some point, perhaps a new static instance will be created?

(I am not interested in relying on destruction order between objects, e.g. where I declare the global `Logger` instance.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing more of your program, the general answer is yes. The destruction of that static map can cause your program to have undefined behavior:

> [**[basic.start.term]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.term)
>
> 3 If the completion of the constructor or dynamic initialization of an
>   object with static storage duration strongly happens before that of
>   another, the completion of the destructor of the second is sequenced
>   before the initiation of the destructor of the first [...]
>
> 4 If a function contains a block-scope object of static or thread
>   storage duration that has been destroyed and the function is called
>   during the destruction of an object with static or thread storage
>   duration, the program has undefined behavior if the flow of control
>   passes through the definition of the previously destroyed block-scope
>   object. Likewise, the behavior is undefined if the block-scope object
>   is used indirectly (i.e., through a pointer) after its destruction.

In general, static objects are destroyed in reverse order to being initialized. So hypothetically, if you have a static object that is initialized early, before the map in the logger, and it logs something in its own destructor, you'll get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

> I am not interested in relying on destruction order between objects

You should, since that is exactly what determines whether `FormatMessage` is safe to call during the program shutdown.

The code that runs during shutdown is destructors of static objects, and function registered with `atExit`.

> Can I rely on a function-scoped static variable for a method called during program shutdown?

You cannot rely on it in general, but you can rely on it in certain circumstances.

It is safe to rely on static objects in `atExit`, so it is safe to call `FormatMessage` there. Unless you can guarantee the order of destruction between particular static object `s`, and `enum2str`, it is not safe to use `FormatMessage` in the destructor of `s`.

Static objects are guaranteed to be destroyed in reverse order of their construction. Therefore you can rely on `enum2str` existing during destruction of the subset of static objects whose constructors call `FormatMessage`, because calling `FormatMessage` in the constructor ensures that `enum2str` will have been constructed before that dependent static object has finished constructing.

There is a trick to relying on a static object regardless of the order of destruction: Never destruct the dependee. This can be achieved by using a static function scope pointer to a dynamically allocated object, that you intentionally never delete. As a drawback, this will trigger diagnostics in memory analyzers and may increase the blood pressure of your dogmatic co-workers.

Comment: Thanks! I think that, to whatever extent possible, I'd rather fix my methods to run reliably, than rely on being able to guarantee a precise destruction order between globally-defined objects. That's a neat workaround :D